# powershell sorting files to a folders

Tags: sorting, powershell

have anyone made similar script? I am new on powershell and would like some help.
My task:
I have a folder with many subfolders, for egz: \mydisc\myfolder****\
I want to find subfolders containing word "first" in folder: myfolder, and from those folders to sort files into new folders called by the file type.

For example

```
\\mydisc\myfolder\qwerty\first_folder
```

containing

```
new.txt
second.pptx
file.docx
one.txt
```

puts all files to new directories:

```
\\mydisc\sortedfiles

new.txt and one.txt -> \\mydisc\sortedfiles\txt

second.pptx -> \\mydisc\sortedfiles\pptx

file.docx -> \\mydisc\sortedfiles\docx
```

If anything is unclear , just ask me. 
Thank you wery much.

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30073195/1630171). Please don't do this. If you need to provide additional information, edit your original question instead of posting a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a homework question since you haven't shown any of your code, but I'll bite. This is how you move items to subfolders depending on their extension, it should give you something to work with. If you put some effort and post the code you tried so far I can edit this answer.

```
$path = "C:\TEMP"
foreach ($file in (get-childitem -file $path))
{
    $newpath = "$($path)\$($file.extension.trimstart('.'))"
    md $newpath -force
    move-item $file $newpath
}
```

Comment: thanks, will try to use this in my code.

Comment: Tested this script, 
It creates new folders by file type, but it doesnt move files to their locations.

Comment: A bit modified this code and now works, thanks.